# How to get a list of input languages on a Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I've tried to get a list of input languages on my **Samsung Galaxy S4**. I've set two input languages in the settings: English(US) and Russian. I've used this code for getting it:

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
List<InputMethodInfo> list = inputMethodManager.getEnabledInputMethodList();

for (InputMethodInfo info : list){
    List<InputMethodSubtype> inputMethodSubtypeList = inputMethodManager
                    .getEnabledInputMethodSubtypeList(info, true);
}
```

But the size of inputMethodSubtypeList is always 0 when info is **com.sec.android.inputmethod.SamsungKeypad**.

Also *inputMethodManager.getCurrentInputMethodSubtype()* and *inputMethodManager.getLastInputMethodSubtype()* return null always.

So how can I get a list of input languages on this device?

Thanks in advance.